# Inconsistency of mpath device name

Tags: 16.04, multipath

In Ubuntu 16.04, I installed multipath-tools package to enable multipath. After login a iSCSI device, I used the command "multipath -ll" to get the mpath device name, and then query in the directory "/dev/mapper". It shows that the device does not exist in the directory "/dev/mapper".

Finally, I found that the device name in "dev/mapper" is inconsistent with the one displayed in the output of the command "multipath -l".

Is this an issue in Ubuntu16.04? I tried in Ubuntu14.04, and they are consistent.

Here is environment I used

`` stack@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
stack@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg -l |grep  multipath-tools
ii  multipath-tools                    0.5.0+git1.656f8865-5ubuntu2.1      amd64        maintain multipath block device access
stack@ubuntu:~$
stack@ubuntu:~$ ll /dev/mapper/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       80 Jul 26 17:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root     4560 Jul 26 17:09 ../
brw-rw----  1 root disk 252,   0 Jul 26 17:09 36006016013003e00c56c0ff5a353e611
crw-------  1 root root  10, 236 Jul 25 23:46 control
stack@ubuntu:~$ sudo multipath -ll
36006016013003e00a90c8cc0a553e611 dm-0 DGC,VRAID
size=1.0G features='2 queue_if_no_path retain_attached_hw_handler' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=50 status=active
| |- 12:0:0:229 sde 8:64  active ready running
| `- 13:0:0:229 sdg 8:96  active ready running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=10 status=enabled
  |- 11:0:0:229 sdc 8:32  active ready running
  `- 14:0:0:229 sdi 8:128 active ready running
stack@ubuntu:~$ ll /dev/disk/by-path/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 300 Jul 26 17:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 Jul 26 17:09 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 26 17:09 ip-192.168.3.52:3260-iscsi-iqn.1992-04.com.emc:cx.apm00153906536.b5-lun-0 -> ../../sdh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 26 17:09 ip-192.168.3.52:3260-iscsi-iqn.1992-04.com.emc:cx.apm00153906536.b5-lun-229 -> ../../sdi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 26 17:09 ip-192.168.3.53:3260-iscsi-iqn.1992-04.com.emc:cx.apm00153906536.a5-lun-0 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 26 17:09 ip-192.168.3.53:3260-iscsi-iqn.1992-04.com.emc:cx.apm00153906536.a5-lun-229 -> ../../sdg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 26 17:09 ip-192.168.4.52:3260-iscsi-iqn.1992-04.com.emc:cx.apm00153906536.a4-lun-0 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 26 17:09 ip-192.168.4.52:3260-iscsi-iqn.1992-04.com.emc:cx.apm00153906536.a4-lun-229 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 26 17:09 ip-192.168.4.53:3260-iscsi-iqn.1992-04.com.emc:cx.apm00153906536.b4-lun-0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 26 17:09 ip-192.168.4.53:3260-iscsi-iqn.1992-04.com.emc:cx.apm00153906536.b4-lun-229 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 25 23:46 pci-0000:00:07.1-ata-2 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 25 23:46 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 25 23:46 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 25 23:46 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 25 23:46 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part5 -> ../../sda5
stack@ubuntu:~$ sudo udevadm info  /dev/mapper/36006016013003e00c56c0ff5a353e611
P: /devices/virtual/block/dm-0
N: dm-0
L: 50
S: disk/by-id/dm-name-36006016013003e00a90c8cc0a553e611
S: disk/by-id/dm-uuid-mpath-36006016013003e00a90c8cc0a553e611
S: disk/by-id/scsi-36006016013003e00a90c8cc0a553e611
S: disk/by-id/wwn-0x6006016013003e00a90c8cc0a553e611
S: disk/by-label/cirros-rootfs
S: disk/by-uuid/d42bb4a4-04bb-49b0-8821-5b813116b17b
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-mpath-36006016013003e00a90c8cc0a553e611 /dev/disk/by-uuid/d42bb4a4-04bb-49b0-8821-5b813116b17b /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-36006016013003e00a90c8cc0a553e611 /dev/disk/by-label/cirros-rootfs /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x6006016013003e00a90c8cc0a553e611 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36006016013003e00a90c8cc0a553e611
E: DEVNAME=/dev/dm-0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/dm-0
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: DM_ACTIVATION=1
E: DM_NAME=36006016013003e00a90c8cc0a553e611
E: DM_STATE=ACTIVE
E: DM_SUSPENDED=0
E: DM_TABLE_STATE=LIVE
E: DM_TYPE=scsi
E: DM_UDEV_DISABLE_DM_RULES_FLAG=1
E: DM_UDEV_DISABLE_SUBSYSTEM_RULES_FLAG=1
E: DM_UDEV_PRIMARY_SOURCE_FLAG=1
E: DM_UDEV_RULES=1
E: DM_UUID=mpath-36006016013003e00a90c8cc0a553e611
E: DM_WWN=0x6006016013003e00a90c8cc0a553e611
E: ID_FS_LABEL=cirros-rootfs
E: ID_FS_LABEL_ENC=cirros-rootfs
E: ID_FS_TYPE=ext3
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_FS_UUID=d42bb4a4-04bb-49b0-8821-5b813116b17b
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=d42bb4a4-04bb-49b0-8821-5b813116b17b
E: ID_FS_VERSION=1.0
E: MAJOR=252
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=62597391570
stack@ubuntu:~$ ``